# how to automate datapower deployment

Tags: ibm-datapower

I want to know if there are anyways to automate datapower deployment. I have seen DpAdmin and DPBuddy are available in the market, but is there anyway we can do it ourselves writing some ant scripts and integrating with Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. There is a web service API that you can access most of the features. It's called "SOMA".

An old, but rather good eBook.
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4446.pdf

More stuff on it here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1308_tuli3/1308_tuli3.html

You can setup anything that does HTTPS/POST and send scripted xml files containing the SOAP envelope if you do not wish to make a complete SOAP client.